# RPM %post scriptlet best practice

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec

I'm trying to track down what is the best practices for the %pre/%post scriptlets in an rpm.spec file.

Specifically I have a system that has a pretty complicated installation. Among other things, it needs to do a lot of "Security-Enhanced Linux" customizations, iptable editing, user creation (with passwords) and "chown"-ing, etc.

The question is where to do this? Should this be put into the pre/post scriptlets? The best practice seems to be to keep these as [simple as possible and definitely don't make it interactive](http://rpm5.org/docs/rpm-guide.html#id3030792).

I have noticed that the Postgres installer (and some others) do a "manual post install" step where the root user needs to run a script to do certain things like set the postgres user's password etc. You can see it below where the rpm prints this: `To initialize, run /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg start as root user.`

Here are the extracted scriptlets:

```
rpm -qp --scripts postgres-9.1.2-1.i386.openscg.rpm
```

preinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):

```
if [ "$1" = "2" ]; then
  #Perform maintenance tasks before server upgrade begins.
  #Determine if server is running, stops it.
  /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg status &> /dev/null
  if [ "$?" = "0" ];
  then
   /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg stop
   touch /tmp/pg_9.1.stopped
  fi
fi
```

postinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):

```
if type "/usr/bin/chcon" &> /dev/null ; then
  /usr/bin/chcon -t textrel_shlib_t $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/lib/libedit.so &> /dev/null 
fi

#Create a soft link to init script
if [ ! -f /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg ]
then
  ln -s $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/bin/postgres-9.1-openscg /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg
fi


#In case of upgrade, dump environment values file
#if [ "$1" = "2" ];
#then
  #Fix for psql dumb terminal issue
  LD_PRELOAD_VALUE=""
  for libreadline in `find -L /lib  -type f -name libreadline.\* 2> /dev/null`
  do
    LD_PRELOAD_VALUE="$libreadline:$LD_PRELOAD_VALUE"
  done
  if [ x"$LD_PRELOAD_VALUE" != x"" ];
  then
    LD_PRELOAD_VALUE="export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD_VALUE"
  fi

  #Dump environment values
cat <<ENVEOF > $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/pg91-openscg.env 
#!/bin/bash
$LD_PRELOAD_VALUE
export PGHOME=$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX
export PGDATA=$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/data
export PATH=$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/bin:\$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/lib:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PGUSER=postgres
export PGDATABASE=postgres
ENVEOF

 #Determine port from postgresql.conf
 PGPORT_VALUE=""
 if [ -f $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/data/postgresql.conf ]; then
  PGPORT_VALUE=`grep "port =" $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/data/postgresql.conf | sed -e      "s/^.*port[[:space:]]=[[:space:]]\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/"`
  PGPORT_VALUE="export PGPORT=$PGPORT_VALUE"
  cat <<ENVEOF >> $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/pg91-openscg.env 
$PGPORT_VALUE
ENVEOF
 fi

#fi

# If it is an upgrade, and we stopped a running server, start it.
if [ "$1" = "2" -a -f /tmp/pg_9.1.stopped ];
then
  rm /tmp/pg_9.1.stopped
  /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg start
fi

if [ "$1" = "1" ];
then
  echo "PostgreSQL 9.1 is now installed in $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX."
  echo
  echo "To initialize, run /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg start"
  echo "as root user."
fi
if [ "$1" = "2" ];
then
  echo "PostgreSQL 9.1 is upgraded in $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX."
fi
```

preuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):

```
if [ "$1" = "0" ]; then
  #Action is uninstallation, not called due to upgrade of a new package

  #Determine if server is running, stops it.
  /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg status &> /dev/null
  if [ "$?" = "0" ];
  then
   echo "Attempting to stop server..."
   /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg stop
  fi

  echo "Attempting to update server startup status..." 
  if type "/sbin/chkconfig" &> /dev/null ; then
   /sbin/chkconfig --del postgres-9.1-openscg 
  fi
fi
```

postuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):

```
if [ "$1" = "0" ]; then
  #Action is uninstallation, not called due to upgrade of a new package
  rm /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg
  echo "Uninstallation complete."
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

If you mean best practice as related to user interaction while RPM installation, there is no question. DON'T do this. Do whatever not needs user interaction in the scriptlets, and either tell the user to run a script after installation, or get all information in the first run of the app.

Comment: No... I get that interactive is bad... For one i bet it breaks yum. My question is more... Is it ok to inject entries into the iptables config as part of an RPM scriptlet? Should you tell the user you're doing this? Should you break this out like postgres does and ask the user to run a "post install script"?

Comment: Both ways are OK and good practice. The way you should do it depends in this case on the users. Are they technical persons? Do they understand the consequences of applying or not applying the iptables rules? etc. BTW, I set iptables during O/S installation, in the kickstart.

Comment: This is a commercial product so the users are probably a mix of users. I would think that in some cases users would be really freaked out. Suppose this is installed in a government/military system, and the installer is now opening port and messing with other system configs. Kickstart i think is a bit different since you wrote the script so you know what you are doing. I think the lesson is that "this is a fine line, that you should walk with care".

Comment: Absolutely. Good luck!